# Как нарисовать эллипс по координатам на Image?

Tags: c#, wpf, графика

Есть класс который позволяет нарисовать эллипс по координатам x, y на канвасе. Как можно нарисовать такой же эллипс по координатам, только не на канвасе а на Image?

```
class draw
{
    public static void circle(double x, double y, int width, int height, Canvas cv)
    {

        Ellipse circle = new Ellipse()
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            Stroke = Brushes.Red,
            StrokeThickness = 6
        };

        cv.Children.Add(circle);

        circle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)x);
        circle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (double)y);
    }
}

draw.circle(x, y, 10, 10, cavRoot);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как можно нарисовать такой же эллипс по координатам, только не на канвасе а на Image?

Одно другому не противоречит - можно разместить на Canvas Image, а поверх него нарисовать эллипс. Но механизм для рисования на изображении в WPF тоже существует, это DrawingVisual и RenderTargetBitmap:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {        
        public void circle(double x, double y, int width, int height, Image img)
        {
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, img.ActualWidth, img.ActualHeight);
            DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();

            if (rect.Width == 0 || rect.Height == 0)
            {
                rect.Width = img.Width;
                rect.Height = img.Height;
            }

            using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
            {
                dc.DrawImage(img.Source,rect);
                dc.DrawEllipse(null, new Pen(Brushes.Red, 6), new Point(x+width/2, y+height/2), width/2, height/2);
            }

            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                (int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
            rtb.Render(visual);
            img.Source = rtb;
        }


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Test\Images\test.jpg"));
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            circle(10, 10, 50, 50, img);
        }
    }
}
```

Данный код хорош работает, если изображение отображается в Image в натуральную величину. Если оно уменьшено, типично для растровой графики, будет потеря качества. Чтобы уменьшить ее, можно вот так изменить код отрисовки, добавив перемасштабирование:

```
public void circle(double x, double y, int width, int height, Image img)
{
    double k = img.ActualWidth / img.Source.Width;
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, img.Source.Width, img.Source.Height);
    DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();

    if (rect.Width == 0 || rect.Height == 0)
    {
        rect.Width = img.Width;
        rect.Height = img.Height;
    }

    if (k == 0)
    {
        k = img.Width / img.Source.Width;
    }

    //пересчитаем координаты с учетом масштабного коэффициента
    x = x / k;
    y = y / k;
    width = (int)Math.Round((double)width / k);
    height = (int)Math.Round((double)height / k);

    using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        dc.DrawImage(img.Source,rect);
        dc.DrawEllipse(null, new Pen(Brushes.Red, 6/k), new Point(x+width/2, y+height/2), width/2, height/2);
    }

    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
    rtb.Render(visual);
    img.Source = rtb;
}
```

Но предпочтительнее было бы использовать способ с добавлением Image в Canvas и рисованием фигуры на Canvas поверх него. При таком способе полностью задействована векторная графика и потери качества не будет независимо от масштаба. Преобразовать итоговый результат в растровое изображение вы все равно сможете, используя RenderTargetBitmap уже на Canvas.

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает прекрасно, только очень сильно портит качество изображения. Сам image в высоком разрешении и качестве, можно ли сделать так чтобы таким он и оставался?

Comment: @FredPerry обновил ответ